# getting a div to flash for 1 second using setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, delay, settimeout

im trying to get a set of four different colored div's to flash for a second in a random sequence that keeps repeating adding one more flash each time, by adding a class that sets their opacity to 0, but only the last div in the sequence appears to be flashing, here is the javascript code:

```
  $(function() {
      x="";

      for(i=0;i<3;i++){
          x+=String(Math.floor(Math.random()*4)+1);
          $("#test").append(x);
          j=0;
          flashinglight();
          $("#red").removeClass("redflash");
          $("#blue").removeClass("blueflash");
          $("#yellow").removeClass("yellowflash");
          $("#green").removeClass("greenflash");
      };
  })

function flashinglight(){
    if(j<x.length){

        setTimeout(function(){
            $("#red").removeClass("redflash");
            $("#yellow").removeClass("yellowflash");
            $("#green").removeClass("greenflash");
            $("#blue").removeClass("blueflash");
            if(x[j]=="1"){ 
                $("#red").addClass("redflash");
            }
            else if(x[j]=="2"){
                $("#yellow").addClass("yellowflash");
            }
            else if(x[j]=="3"){
                $("#green").addClass("greenflash");
            }
            else if(x[j]=="4"){                       
                $("#blue").addClass("blueflash");
            }  
            j+=1;
            flashinglight();

        },1000);
    }
    else{
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll be glad to know it can ba a lot simpler than that. :-) See comments inline:

```js
// Your existing ready callback
$(function() {
  // Array of color names
  var colors = ["red", "blue", "yellow", "green"];
  
  // Start
  flashlight();
  
  function flashlight() {
    // Get a random color
    var c = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
    // Get the matching element
    var elm = $("#" + c);
    // And class
    var cls = c + "flash";
    // Add the class
    elm.addClass(cls);
    // A second later...
    setTimeout(function() {
      // Remove it
      elm.removeClass(cls);
      // And run again
      flashlight();
    }, 1000);
  }
});
```

```css
.container div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
#red {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
#blue {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
#yellow {
  border: 2px solid yellow;
}
#green {
  border: 2px solid green;
}
.redflash {
  background-color: red;
}
.blueflash {
  background-color: blue;
}
.yellowflash {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.greenflash {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="red"></div>
  <div id="blue"></div>
  <div id="yellow"></div>
  <div id="green"></div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

That "flashes" for a full second before moving on to the next. If you need a shorter flash and a delay between them, it's just a matter of setting up a second timer.

Watching that for a moment, it bothered me when the same color was picked twice. So if you want a version that excludes the current color when picking the next:

```js
// Your existing ready callback
$(function() {
  // Array of color names
  var colors = ["red", "blue", "yellow", "green"];
  
  // The current color
  var color = null;
  
  // Start
  flashlight();
  
  function flashlight() {
    // Pick a random color, excluding the one we're currently using
    var available = colors.filter(function(c) {
      return c !== color;
    });
    color = available[Math.floor(Math.random() * available.length)];
    // Get the matching element
    var elm = $("#" + color);
    // And class
    var cls = color + "flash";
    // Add the class
    elm.addClass(cls);
    // A second later...
    setTimeout(function() {
      // Remove it
      elm.removeClass(cls);
      // And run again
      flashlight();
    }, 1000);
  }
});
```

```css
.container div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
#red {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
#blue {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
#yellow {
  border: 2px solid yellow;
}
#green {
  border: 2px solid green;
}
.redflash {
  background-color: red;
}
.blueflash {
  background-color: blue;
}
.yellowflash {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.greenflash {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="red"></div>
  <div id="blue"></div>
  <div id="yellow"></div>
  <div id="green"></div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```